# Accessing PHP variable value with : and { in it

Tags: php, arrays

Using Gravity Forms API code GFAPI::get_entries returns an array. Most of the values are straight forward and I have no issues accessing them. However, when it outputs the "List" field it looks like this:

```
[44] => a:3:{i:0;a:5:{s:7:"Address";s:17:"111 Long St";s:4:"City";s:10:"Southfield";s:5:"State";s:2:"MI";s:3:"Zip";s:5:"48033";s:4:"Type";s:17:"House - Townhouse";}}
```

How would I set "111 Long St" to a variable? I will need all of the values but I'm sure I can figure it out once I have the answer to getting the Address.

Thanks!

[Edit]
So this is mostly my working code with a few changes to make it easier to read:

```
$search_criteria["field_filters"][] = array( "key" => "id", value => "10" );
$entries = GFAPI::get_entries( $form_id, $search_criteria );
```

...

```
$unserializeArray = unserialize($GLOBALS['entries'][0][44]);
return $unserializeArray[0]["Address"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

that's a serialized array in PHP, similar to JSON representation

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the fast reply! I figured it out. I will approve answer when it lets me. I will also edit my question incase anyone stumbles on this.